# jQuery load() not working for further future menu anchor

Tags: jquery, jquery-load

I have a `HTML` page with menu anchor. The page getting content is from link click via `j Query` `load()` for specified url. Suppose first page have menu links as  **Page2,  Page3** 
click on **Page2** and content load via `j Query` load();
The loaded page content having further menu anchor links **page3 , index**. 
When i am clicking on **page3** `j Query` `load()` is not working. means content is not loading from further link.

**why the further future link is not working**

http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_kumar/prLN6/5/

Code 
**index.html**

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $(".showMenu").on("click",function() {
                        $(".ulMenu").fadeIn().css({ 'display':'block'});
                    });

                    $('.ulMenu').mouseleave(function() {
                        $(this).fadeOut('slow').css({ 'display':'none'});
                    });

                    $('ul.ulMenu li a').on("click",function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $("#container").load(this.href, function(){

                            }).hide().fadeIn('fast');
                            return false;
                        });
                })
            </script>
            <style>
                .ulMenu{ display:none;}
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id='container'>
                <div id='mainPage'>
                    <div id='mainPageMenu'>
                        <ul class='showMenu'><li>Show menu</li></ul>
                        <ul id='mainPageMenuUl' class='ulMenu'>
                            <li class="menu"><a href='page2.html'>Page2</a></li>
                            <li class="menu"><a href='page3.html'>Page3</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    Main page Main page Main page Main page Main page Main
                </div>
            </div>

        </body>
    </html>
```

**page2.html**

```
<div id='page2'>
    <div id='page2Menu'>
        <ul class='showMenu'><li>Show menu</li></ul>
        <ul id='page2MenuUl' class='ulMenu'>
            <li class="menu"><a href='page3.html'>Page3</a></li>
            <li class="menu"><a href='index.html'>Main Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    page 2 page 2 page 2 page 2 page 2 page 2 page 2  
</div>
```

**page3.html**

```
<div id='page3'>
    <div id='page3Menu'>
        <ul class='showMenu'><li>Show menu</li></ul>
            <ul id='page3MenuUl' class='ulMenu'>
                <li class="menu"><a href='page4.html'>Page4</a></li>
                <li class="menu"><a href='index.html'>main Page Menu</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    page 3 page 3 page 3 page 3 page 3 page 3 page 3 page 3 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem

```
$('ul.ulMenu li a').on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#container").load(this.href, function () {   // you are replacing the html contents with the returned data
    }).hide().fadeIn('fast');
    return false;
});
```

Since they are new elements just loaded into the DOM, they don't have any event handlers attached to them because they did not exist at the time of binding.  What you would have to do is

Delegate to a parent that exists at the time of binding and will be static

Since you are loading into the #container div - you can always bind it to that element

```
$("#container").on('click','.showMenu',function(){
     $(".ulMenu").fadeIn().css({ 'display':'block'});
});

$('#container').on('mouseleave','.ulMenu',function(){
     $(this).fadeOut('slow').css({ 'display':'none'});
});

$('#container').on('click','ul.ulMenu li a',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $("#container").load(this.href, function(){

      }).hide().fadeIn('fast');
      return false;
});
```

Or bind new event handlers in the success function to the elements after they are loaded

Comment: Ohh that's gr8. it approx solved.. but one problem still reside. when next page is loaded its menu is already opened . it should be hidden.

Comment: @PuzzledBoy What do you mean it's gone?

Comment: @PuzzledBoy  Also I forgot to pass in the event for the anchor click.. just edited my answer to add it

Comment: No mistake was there in your code. Sir..
you miss "e" in "function(e){"

Comment: yes i catch it ans solved .. thankx a lot sir ji.. and please no angry angry sir ji... :-)